# Magento admin denied issue

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, permissions, adminmenu

We are able to login in magento admin but we can not access any menu please tell me what is reason . We have created a new user also from database but no help .

Please check screen shot here-

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/02e5lhql3c

Answer (score 0):

Two tables you have to modified:

1. admin_user
2. admin_role

   inside admin_user add new user or update existing by change password in MD5.

   inside admin_role assign the role

For more details see [here](https://www.atwix.com/magento/reset-admin-password-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

When this problem occurs after adding a new user, the problem could be that no role for that user is selected.

If you can still login with another user, you can simply select a role for the new user and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Actually  we are not  getting any menu link in admin then how we can select roles. by database we have done but not getting any menu